# Can I use group_vars/all.yml in community.aws.ec2_vpc_route_table Ansible Module?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

For example, I want to take this example play below.

```
# demo_setup.yml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - name: Set up NAT-protected route table
    community.aws.ec2_vpc_route_table:
      vpc_id: vpc-1245678
      region: us-west-1
      tags:
        Name: Internal
      subnets:
        - 'SMTP Subnet'
        - 'Database Subnet'
        - 'Bastion Subnet'
      routes:
        - dest: 0.0.0.0/0
          instance_id: "{{ nat.instance_id }}"
```

Then use the group_vars/all.yml to call my variables

```
# group_vars/all.yml
vpc: vpc-1245678
region: us-west-1
igw: igw-036dde5c85EXAMPLE
subnet_list:
  -  name: 'SMTP Subnet'
  -  name: 'Database Subnet'
  -  name: 'Database Subnet'
```

```
# demo_setup.yml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - name: Set up NAT-protected route table
    community.aws.ec2_vpc_route_table:
      vpc_id: {{ vpc }}
      region: {{ region }}
      tags:
        Name: Internal
      subnets:
        - "{{ subnet_list }}"
      routes:
        - dest: 0.0.0.0/0
          instance_id: "{{ igw }}"
```

The problem I am having is how can I input my **subnet_list** and place it in the **community.aws.ec2_vpc_route_table** module.

Comment: => `subnets: "{{ subnet_list | map(attribute='name') | list }}"`. Get familiar with [filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html). Meanwhile, if you don't really need those elements to be dictionaries, I suggest you follow the answer from @jellycsc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making `subnet_list` as a list of dictionaries, just make it a list of strings. This will make your life easier.

```
subnet_list:
  -  SMTP Subnet
  -  Database Subnet
  -  Database Subnet2
```

```
# demo_setup.yml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - name: Set up NAT-protected route table
    community.aws.ec2_vpc_route_table:
      vpc_id: "{{ vpc }}"
      region: "{{ region }}"
      tags:
        Name: Internal
      subnets: "{{ subnet_list }}"
      routes:
        - dest: 0.0.0.0/0
          instance_id: "{{ igw }}"
```

Comment: That was it plus the `"{{ subnet_list }}"` was in the wrong place in my play. Thank you @jellycsc